# How to modiffy Highchart size with slide effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, charts, highcharts

I have multiples charts on the same page in two columns, and I have a button to  slide right using jquery `animate()`, having the left column charts hiding the right columns charts.

My problem is :

Using the function `chart.reflow()` I can only resize the charts when animate has ended, it is not beautiful.

an other problem append when I reflow, i lose `.brighten()` property on pie charts (Only on pie charts)

A little example from my fiddle to describe my problem:

```
$('#resize').click(function(){
    $('#first').animate({
        width : '100%'
    }, 600);
    $('#second').animate({
        width : 'toggle',
        opacity : 'toggle'
    }, 600).queue(function(){
        $('#first').highcharts().reflow();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8t6ev/1/

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to use the [step option of .animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

```
    $('#resize').click(function(){
    $('#first').animate({
        width : '100%'
    },{
    duration: 600,
    step: function() {
      $('#first').highcharts().reflow();
    }
    });

    $('#second').animate({
        width : 'toggle',
        opacity : 'toggle'
    }, 600).queue(function(){
        $('#first').highcharts().reflow();
    });
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8t6ev/2/)

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what i'm searching! I looked for it during a whole dqy!